# Is this polynomial time for greatest prime factor of odd numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics

For natural numbers $n$ and $x,$ the number of $n^{th}$ roots that have $x$ in the whole numbers place can be represented as $(x+1)^{n}-x^{n}.$ For $p$ prime,

$(x+1)^{n}-x^{n}-1\equiv0\bmod p$ iff $n=p^{k}.$

The AKS test uses this identity at $k=1$ giving,

$(x+1)^{n}-x^{n}-1\equiv0\bmod n$ iff $n$ is prime.

I have found that it is also interesting if we evaluate the exponent at only the even numbers $2n,$ meaning in this form,

$(x+1)^{2n}-x^{2n}-1.$

In this form, the smallest number $m$ that will not divide each and every coefficient of the expansion seems to be the greatest prime factor of $2n+1.$ In other words, If you choose $2n=32$ then dividing by $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$and $10$ will give some integer coefficients, but when you divide by the greatest prime factor of $33$ which is $11$, there are none. This is also the smallest number for which that occurs. So this can be used as a test.

Now to determine what this greatest prime factor is it seems that you would have to check every term, or at least half of them, so I'm not sure if it can be afforded the same computation simplification as the AKS test, but this still may be a polynomial time test for greatest prime factor of $2n+1.$

So my question is, does this idea afford a polynomial time test for this or is it a useless idea?

To my best knowledge, this is unknown. But, I of course could be wrong.

Comment: Is the question, whether the prime-number-test can be used to factor an arbitary odd number in polynomial time ? Then, the answer is : no, since no polynomial time algorithm for factoring is known.

Comment: @Peter No. not factoring, just to identify the greatest prime factor. The AKS test uses that only a prime will divide. The test I'm talking about specifically identifies the greatest prime factor because it is the minimal number such that there are no integer coefficients.

Comment: If this would work for every composite number, we would have an efficient method to factor any number.

Comment: @Peter It does work for all odd numbers. I edited the question to be clear. You can specifically identify the greatest prime factor of $2n+1$ because it is the minimum number that leaves no integer coefficient's. I'm asking if it can be reduced in time and such. I think its already polynomial.

Comment: If you can find any one factor in polynomial time then you can find all of them in polynomial time, because at worst you have to do your procedure $\log_2(N)$ times.

Comment: And it is very unlikely that this method has been overlooked. So, the determination of $n$ currently cannot be made in polynomial time.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I think it is maybe possible that it has been over looked however because an even exponent was of no interest in identifying primes and finding the smallest number that leaves all non-integer coefficients in this may not have been an interesting pursuit. I could be wrong. Try it for yourself, it does identify the greatest prime factor.

Comment: I would assume, like most, that it must not be an efficient way to find factors of a generic odd integer. But I think it's a good question nonetheless, and hope it gets a good answer.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but $(x+1)^{2n} - x^{2n}$ has almost $2n$ non-zero coefficients, almost all of which are much much larger than $2n + 1$. How is finding the smallest prime not dividing any of these $2n$ big numbers easier than say finding the smallest prime dividing $2n+1$ by trial divison? At least using trial divison one only has to check up to $\sqrt{2n+1}$ or so.

Comment: Good argument! My guess is that the method works well if $a$ is a pseudoprime to some base. Or, the other possibility, it finds the possible factors efficiently only, if the number is prime. If we knew the order with respect to some number $a$, we could find a factor virtually immediately. This idea is used in Shor's algorithm. But is is infeasible to find the order of a very large number to an arbitary base (unless the number is pseudoprime to some base).

Comment: @pjs36 I did not say that the question is not interesting. But it is hard for me to believe that such a simple method allows an efficient factoring.

Comment: Good points. I'm not sure if it can be made faster by whatever means. I'm just introducing the idea for feedback. and I like the feedback given so far. Excellent points.

Comment: Try to find a prime factor of $4^{256}+253$ with this method. This is a composite number, and I do not know any prime factor of it. I asked for a factor on this site, without a result yet.

Comment: @Peter Someone else would have to write the code, I don't know how.

Comment: Sounds like it's no good from the arguments. If someone writes a good detailed answer for or against the ups and downs, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this question was answered in the comments, so I'm using an answer to my own question to close the question. If anyone has an answer to give they are welcome to do so and I will probably accept it.